# React this.state going outdated

Tags: reactjs

I have the below component which fetches a JSON response from a (Django) server and renders the results to a `<ListingInline />` via a map on the `listings` state. This works as expected.

```
class Listings extends Component {
    state = {
        listings: [],
    }

    loadListings() {
        const endpoint = '/api/listings/'
        const csrfToken = Cookies.get('csrftoken')
        let thisComp = this
        let lookupOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken
            },
            credentials: 'include'
        }

        fetch(endpoint, lookupOptions)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json()
        }).then(function(responseData) {
            // console.log(responseData.results)
            thisComp.setState({
                listings: responseData.results
            })
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("error", error)
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            listings: []
        })
        this.loadListings()
    }

    render() {
        const {listings} = this.state
        return (
            <Container className='pl-0 pr-0' style={{paddingTop: this.props.topPadding, height: '100vh'}} fluid='true'>
                <div className='row p-0 no-gutters' style={{height: '100%'}}>
                    <div className='col-md-6' style={{height: '100%'}}>
                        <Scrollbars style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}>
                            {listings.length > 0 ? listings.map((listingItem) => {
                                return (
                                    <ListingInline listing={listingItem} />
                                )
                            }) : <p>No Listings Found</p>}
                        </Scrollbars>
                    </div>
                    <div className='col-md-6 d-none d-md-block' style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}>
                        <Map listings={listings} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

export default Listings;
```

However, just below that I try to render a `<Map />` component with a listings prop equals to `listings`. However, this fails to get passed onto the `<Map />` component.

I'm sure there's probably something about lifecycle I haven't understood quite correctly, but I cannot find any explanations as to why the above does not work. And beyond that, what would be the correct way of essentially passing the same data to 2 different components?

Thanks.

**Edit:**
The `<Map />` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Map extends Component {
    render() {
        const {listings} = this.props
        return (
            <div>{listings}</div>
        )
    }
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: It’ll be passed with whatever’s in it—is the component doesn’t know how to handle it before it’s loaded it could cause an issue.

Comment: What does "fails to get passed onto" mean? There could be something going on in the Map component too, which you don't show us, that doesn't respond properly to changed props.

Comment: React can't render objects as children, are there any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors in console. The `<ListingInLine />` is essentialy the same (i.e. rendering some divs after reading this.props), and this works fine.

Comment: Can you replace this line `<div>{listings}</div>` with this `<div>{listings.toString()}</div>` and see if it prints the content of the listing array, or better still you shold console log what comes in as props in the componentDidMount lifecycle method of the map component.

Comment: I might be missing something, but it doesn't look like `loadListings` has access to `this`.You set it to `thisComp` inside the funciton and used it to set state, but I dont see where the function itself gets `this` bound to it.

Comment: I put `const {listings} = this.props` and `console.log(listings)` inside componentDidMount() and console logs a `[]` (i.e. empty array) response.

Comment: Log listings in your parent component too. Is it also an empty array?

Comment: When there is empty array in map do you see `No Listings Found` in the parent component?

Comment: Ok I do get data when I do `const {listings} = this.props` and `console.log(listings)` inside the `render()` function instead of the `componentDidMount()`. Is this.props not available in `componentDidMount()`?

Comment: `componentDidMount` only fires one time after the component mounts. You are calling the function to get your data in that method, so it can't be accessible until after that lifecycle method

Answer (score 0):

Here You passing entire array of listing state rather than just a value..

so to call Map component, either you have to pass Map component in loop by this way..

```
....
{listings.length > 0 ? 
     listings.map((listingItem) => {
              return (
                    <Map listing={listingItem} />
              )
     }) : 
<p>No Listings Found</p>}
```

or You can map listing array in Map component..So your Map component would be like this..

```
{listings.length > 0 ? 
     listings.map((listingItem) => {
              return (
                    <div>{listingItem}</div>
              )
     }) : 
<p>No Listings Found</p>}
```